# Trocar o nome da classe com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estou querendo criar com jQuery a funcionalidade de contraste, onde o usuário ao clicar em um determinado botão, o site ficaria escuro e se clicar novamente, voltaria ao normal. Compramos um template do qual oferece essa funcionalidade, mas da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código dele está assim:

```
    (function() {
        $('<div class="color-picker"><a href="#" class="handle"><i class="icofont icofont-color-bucket"></i></a><div class="settings-header"><h3>Painel de Controle</h3></div><div class="section"><h3 class="color">Cor:</h3><div class="colors"><a href="#" class="color-1" ></a></div></div><div class="section"><h3 class="color">Contraste:</h3><div><a href="#" class="color-inverse"><img class="img img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="assets/images/contraste.png" style="width: 50px" /></a></div></div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
    })();

$(".color-1").on('click',function() {
    $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/color-1.css");
    return false;
});

$(".color-inverse").on('click',function() {
    $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/color-inverse.css");
    return false;
});
```

Gostaria de centralizar os cliques somente no ícone de contraste e retirar o ícone azul. Para isso, tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou:

```
$(".color-1").on('click',function() {
    $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/color-1.css");
    return false;
});

$(".color-inverse").on('click',function() {
        $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/inverse.css");
        var classe = $(this).attr("class");
        //alert(classe);

        if(classe == 'color-inverse'){
          var div = document.querySelector('div');
          div.classList.remove('color-inverse');
          div.classList.add('color-1');
        }else{
          var div = document.querySelector('div');
          div.classList.remove('color-1');
          div.classList.add('color-inverse');

        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Quando usas `document.querySelector('div')` isso vai selecionar a primeira div do DOM, provavelmente com o reso do HTML/DOM dentro, é isso que queres?

Comment: Olá Sérgio. Consegui resolver, não sei se foi da forma correta, mas funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver. Segue o código:

```
(function() {
    $('<div class="color-picker"><a href="#" class="handle"><i class="icofont icofont-color-bucket"></i></a><div class="settings-header"><h3>Painel de Controle</h3></div><div class="section"><h3 class="color">Contraste:</h3><div><div class="colors"><a href="#" class="color-inverse"><img class="img img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="assets/images/contraste.png" style="width: 50px" /></a></div></div></div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
})();

$(".color-inverse").on('click',function() {
  var classe = $(this).attr("class");

    if(classe == "color-inverse"){
     $('.color-inverse').addClass('color-1');
     $('.color-inverse').removeClass('color-inverse');
     $('.color-inverse').removeClass('colors');
     $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/inverse.css");
    }
    if(classe == "color-1"){
     $('.color-1').addClass('color-inverse');
     $('.color-1').removeClass('color-1');
     $('.color-1').addClass('colors');
     $("#color").attr("href", "assets/css/color/color-1.css");
   }
    return false;
});
```